# How can I do in java spring boot not try a database connection on start up?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to know if there is a way in Java Spring boot not to try a connection at startup. What I am trying to do is an integrated SQL server connection. I am trying to generate a .jar with integrated connection and not with SQL credentials. As a developer, I don't have access permissions to the database, but the service account that runs the .jar does.
The thing is that if I try to establish a connection string with integrated authentication it will try to log in with my credentials and it will never be able to, so it will not be able to generate the .jar
At the moment my app is working fine with sql credentials, but I need to migrate to integrated credentials.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>X</groupId>
    <artifactId>X</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>X</name>
    <description>X</description>
    <properties>

        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://X.X.X.X:1433;database=X
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=X
spring.datasource.password=X
server.port=8080
```

I also try adding this line in application.properties with no success:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Don't you want to have a profile and connect with your local profile to a local alternative of SQL Server, H2 or whatever and create prod profile to your jar?

Comment: Maybe I don't know Java Spring boot enought because I don't know what you are talking about when you say a "profile"

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

when you don't choose anything, Spring Boot uses `default`

Comment: Hi @DmytroChasovskyi , I spent the weekend learning about spring profiles. That's not what I need. It's useful, I'm not going to deny you that, and I didn't know about it, but, I'm asking if it is possible not to try a database connection on startup. In any case, even if I used spring profiles, it would not work for me because, as I said, if I try to establish a connection string with integrated authentication it will try to log in with my credentials and not with the ones of the service account and it will never be able to package the .jar

Comment: Cannot you try doing runtime connection build?

There are couple of possibilities to connect to DB: integrated in Spring, not integrated but via `@Configuration` during startup or as a `@Component` when you have service build but, for example, lazily connected to DB. Would anything of the above work for you?

Comment: No, because the entitymanager is built with the credentials specified in the application.properties and it is not correct to generate a new connection in code with the credentials from the code or something like that in a @ Configuration component. I don't think that any of that will work for me because because the credentials cannot be hanging around in some @ configuration component.

Comment: Don't you mind to add more details on how you build the app and how you run the app? Suggestions in the comments under question and answer should fulfil your requirements, I have a feeling that you got the info and don't know how to apply it or initial question is confusing to people who tries to answer. 1. How you build the app? 2. How you run the app locally? 3. How is it supposed to run in prod? 4. What do you mean by "integrated connection"?

Comment: Hello @Dmytro, I don't think that with the information you have provided I can clarify my question. I have passed my question to several people who also work with Spring Boot and they have managed to understand it perfectly. As I said, what I'm trying to do is that when running a package, spring boot doesn't try to make a connection to the database. As simple as that. When a run or package is done, spring boot automatically tries to make a connection to the database to validate that everything is ok. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to break my answer into 4 sections to answer your questions.
1- To do a build I basically run a maven package in IntelliJ. That generates a .jar file that can be run on any windows pc/windows server.
2- Locally to test in development I give a run to my main class in IntelliJ. That brings up my API at 127.0.0.1:[port].

Comment: 3- I have developed a compilation pipeline in Microsoft TFS, which is the tool used by the company I work for, and what it does is generate an application.properties and persistence.xml suitable for production. After that, it makes a package and generates a .jar that will be the one that will be deployed in production.
4- I apologize because perhaps with what I have said before I have confused you. The correct term is "Windows authentification". Windows authentication is a method of identifying a login with credentials supplied by the Windows operating system (OS) of the connecting computer.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is specify in the connection string that Windows authentication method will be used. Therefore, when the service account starts the service (which is the .jar), the credentials it will use are those of the service account and not ones specified in application.properties or in persistence.xml. What this allows is that if you execute the .jar it will use your credentials, if I execute it it will use my credentials, and so on with anyone who executes the .jar.
I hope you have understood, I think I can not be clearer than that haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this anotation on the main class resolve everything

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Instead of

```
@SpringBootApplication()
```

Comment: this will break your prod where the connection was desired though

Comment: Hi @CoderinoJavarino , as I said I was looking to find a way not to try a connection at startup. Of course that if the persistence.xml is not correct it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the service account useing a special spring profile when starting the jar?
Then you could do this in you application.properties:

```
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=serviceProfile 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://${DB_HOST};database=${DB_NAME} 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD} 
server.port=8080
```

The service would start the jar like this:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=serviceProfile -DDB_HOST=X.X.X.X:1433 -DDB_NAME=X -DDB_USER=X -DDB_PASSWORD=X application.jar
```

Comment: As I said before to @Dmytro Chasovskyi Maybe I don't know Java Spring boot enough because I don't know what you are talking about when you say a "profile".

Comment: "Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it only available in certain environments." https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

In your case you will have an environment "dev" where you don't want to have the datasource and the environment "serviceProfile" (or any other name you want to give it) where the service account will have the necessary credentials to use the datasource.

Comment: Hi @Technobabel , please check out my answer to Dmytro before, I answered him about the same topic minutes ago. Also I ask you what about the persistence.xml. I could have differents application.properties like application-production.properties and application-dev.properties but in my persistence.xml it will always point at one or another database

Comment: @GasparZanini I guess, you can use placeholder and sort of override connection to DB by profile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998820/how-to-parameterize-jpa-database-instance-in-persistence-xml